# Can ArcGIS Online navigate and identify large GIS datasets?

Tags: arcgis-online, performance, large-datasets

For my upcoming project, I want to see if ArcGIS Online can provide a viable solution.

Users will need to have access to webmap on their desktops with basic navigation and identify. This will be an internal application.

As far as I know, hosting data on the web is not an issue from security point of view.

I want to know if ArcGIS Online can handle large GIS datasets, it will range from 50,000-250,000 records for some of the basemap data layers.

Comment: This question is way too broad.  It all depends...  I'd suggest editing your question and giving a bit more specifics about what you're trying to accomplish first.  We'd need to know about your use case, what functionality you need, internal vs public facing and other security requirements, etc...  ArcGIS Server isn't just a bigger version of ArcGIS Online.  They have overlapping functionality, but they are not purely replacements for each other, so knowing what you need to do would help answer what you need to do it.

Comment: Are you wanting to store this large dataset(s) in ESRI's cloud, or are you going to store it on your own server?  I can tell you that storing large datasets in ESRI's cloud can get expensive, and/or take up a lot of account credits.  Also, you may have performance issues vs publishing through ArcServer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Cost and performance are the concerns that I have with ArcGIS Online approach. I am hoping to store data on ESRI's cloud.

Comment: Using ArcGis online takes a lot of hard work out of the setup of a web-enabled GIS. As you've indicated that you don't currently have a GIS capability it's probably a good idea just from that aspect. Have you considered alternatives, as it is an internal use only QGIS with PostGIS would be viable and considerably cheaper - provided your end users are ok with installing a new program rather than browsing in an established web application.

Comment: One low cost/low learning curve option would be to use MangoMap (if you are ok with giving them a copy of your data), https://mangomap.com/.

Answer (score 0):

When making mapping apps there is a lot of considerations to make. Some of the things we ask for our clients are:

1. Does your company have a GIS area?
2. How many layers are you planning to show in the app?
3. How many people will be using the app?
4. How many connections per day, hour or even second are you expecting to have?
5. Does your company owns a web server you can use to host the app?

If you can give me some of this information I’ll be able to give you a better answer... In the mean time I can tell you that ArcGiS Online gives you much more than just online mapping, it provides with tools to build layers and to manage your data, anyway, if you are only going to use it to build a web app with navigation and identify, then I’ll recommend you to do some research on other tools like Google maps api for business (quite expensive too if used internally) or even free tools like opengeo suite.

Comment: Currently company doesnt have any GIS capability, there are going to be 6-10 layers, there are approx 10 users and they want to able to see data via web maps, Company doesnt have a dedicated GIS Server at the moment. Since Company doesnt have any GIS infrastructure, this is why I am trying to find out if ArcGIS Online will provide solution that fits their initial needs.

Comment: Considering the number of users and the amount of information to be included in the map, I really think that getting such an expensive service is too much for your current needs. Setting up a simple PC as a server and using OpenGeo suite will solve your mapping needs in a few simple steps and with almost 0 cost (apart from time consumed to set up the software). One thing I´ve found is that ArcGis services require a certain degree of GIS expertise since they were designed to be cloud based  GIS solutions and not just web map solutions.

Comment: opengeo suite is far from free: http://boundlessgeo.com/solutions/opengeo-suite/

Comment: You may want to read fourder into the page, particularly check the "Click for more details..." link on the bottom of the page. OpenGeo Suite is absolutely free to download, install and run on any capable server. "Enterprise" packages referenced on the page are service packages that you can buy if you need assistance, special features,Core development hours and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. For my current requirements, I am limited to ESRI technology option. I need to choose between ArcGIS Server and ArcGIS online.

Comment: As mentioned before by me and others here, having no GIS specialist ArcGis Server will be quite hard to configure and creating maps will need you to actually "learn" to use the software. If you are limited to ESRI (Can’t see why but...) then I´ll say that ArcGis Online will be better for you.